# Could we add the ability to change our votes on review items?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just voted on a review item and immediately realised that I had misread something and voted incorrectly.

I think it would be useful to be able to change such votes after the fact.

I understand that it is possible that your newly changed vote could be biased based on what you can now see of other people's votes however I would argue that users with enough reputation to vote should be able to vote without such bias.

Is it possible this could be something that could get in or is it a pipe dream?

Comment: Any vote can be changed for up to 5 mins after being placed - any reason you can't use that existing feature? Or is this more about the UI for allowing you to do so specifically in the review queue?

Comment: I guess it's not obvious how to change it then.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too used to it - if you click the same arrow you clicked to vote, that will undo it (within the 5 minute period). After 5 minutes your vote won't be changeable until the post is edited. Pretty sure exactly the same thing was asked on meta.stackoverflow in the last week so maybe it's not that obvious a feature

Comment: Oh, yeah I know about that.
I'm referring to accepting or rejecting edits in the review section.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you meant the other kind of voting. I don't think that's the sort of thing that would be changed (I could be wrong obviously) - the ethos has always been "don't click the button until you're sure" in my experience.

Comment: Yeah I get that, that's fair enough. I guess accidents are accidents and that small percentage of accidents can just be ignored.